# Entity Framework Non Identity - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, primary-key, identity

I have a table with a primary Key of ID, this field is not an identity column.  My migration for Entity Framework 6 is

```
 CreateTable(
   "dbo.Action",
    c => new
    {
       ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: false),
       ActionName = c.String(maxLength: 50),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
```

This all looks fairly straight forward to me.  Then I have a method to seed some data:

```
public static void Seed(this DbSet<Action> entitySet)
{
    MainContext dbCtx = DataRepositoryBase<Action>.GetContext(entitySet) as MainContext;
    if (dbCtx != null)
    {
            entitySet.Add(new Action()
            {
                ID = 1,
                ActionName = "Test"
            });                
    }
}
```

It's at the this point I get an error

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'dbo.Action';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated"

As you can see I am clearly providing an value for the ID column.  My suspicion is that Entity Framework is expecting the ID to be an Identity column

The Entity class is very simple

```
[DataContract]
public class Action
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the mapping for the `Action` entity?

Comment: Have you told EF that the ID column is not an identity column?

Comment: Surely that's what I'm doing in the migration when I say identity: false

Comment: No, the migration is just creating the table.

Comment: By default ID is PK Identity. Since you are sing Data annotation you can use DatabaseGenerated attribute to set it

Comment: You posted the `Action` entity class. I haven't worked with Entity Framework in a while, but you should have a "mapping" class where you explicitly map columns to properties, and define which property represents the primary key.

Comment: Entity Framework works on convention and will take ID as the primary key unless otherwise specified. @DavidG has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your migration only creates the table in the database but doesn't tell Entity Framework the the ID property is not an `IDENTITY` column. EF picks the property called ID if you do not tell it which property to use as the primary key, but you also need to tell EF that it's not an IDENTITY column, do this using the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class Action
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key] //This isn't technically needed, but I prefer to be explicit.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the fact that fields name Id are supposed to be primary key and identity.
When EF generate insert statement does not generate value for that field.

You can fix it using

```
[DataContract]
public class Action
{
    [DataMember]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```